# TYPO3 News Translation with Image "Translation Behaviour: Custom Value" isn't working

Tags: typo3, translation, typo3-8.x, image-translation

I'm having a little Problem in TYPO3 8.7 with News Elements and setting a Custom Image for a translation. Im still new to TYPO3.

I want to have the ENGLISH Version of my News to have a different Image than my Standard Language Version, but I can only make the same one work for both or none at all.

First I added a News element with an Image, translated it to english, set Translation behaviour for the Image to "Custom Value", hid the Original Image & then Added a new Image.

I was hoping the English Version would use the new Image but it doesn't. There is not Image at all. Everything else works as expected. When I unhide the old one & use "Translation Behaviour: Value of default language" I get the Standard Image.

I also tried deleting the Standard Image in the Translated Version but nothing works :X

My tt_content.php did not set 'allowLanguageSynchronization'.
The Documentation says that it's "false" by default so I dont think its causing the problem. Some Forum posts suggested that might be the cause for some similar issue, like I said im still new to TYPO3 and I have no idea what I am missing here.

Most research I've done link to this issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272

Edit: Fixed link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check my answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51112753/1588346

And before wasting time on debugging, try this extension:
https://packagist.org/packages/stefanfroemken/repair_translation

If it won't work please attach here the details about your TypoScript configuration, especially `config.sys_language_mode` and `config.sys_language_overlay`.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=language#sys-language-mode

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=language#sys-language-overlay

Comment: Extension worked like a charm. Tyvm. Just had to install it and it worked instantly.